# Automatically scaling font to fit panel

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have an Swing app whose main panel is divided into a 3x2 grid of charts, and the app can be resized, with the charts (JFreeChart) auto scaling.  One of these panels I would like to display the Apdex rating in, which is just text (e.g. '0.89 [0.5]*').  We use the application to display on a monitor visible to everyone, and scale multiple instances of the app that monitor different data centers.  Scaling the Apdex font size to fit available panel space is what I'm after.

Any good ideas?

Comment: Hi. Maybe a code sample or image showing the problem would be helpful here. Sorry, I cannot be more helpful without it. Try also to re-tag the question as JFreeChart.

Comment: See also [Zoom text to be as big as possible within constraints/box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837410).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-reading and rethinking the question I would suggest for you to try calculating it yourself by use of FontMatrics stringWidth with the string and iteratively increasing the font size until you can, i.e. the size evaluated by you versus the available space.

A ready algorithm would be nice but I didn't hear of any.

Good luck, Boro.

Comment: That's sort of what my initial approach was going to be, but I thought this had to have been solved before.

Comment: I would expect it was. But I have never found this algorithm. Please share if you do. A library with this method would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd render it off-screen at some suitably large point size, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287269), and then down-sample it using `AffineTransformOp`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216635).

Comment: +1 nice approach. @trashgod I understand instead of setting the text for a label you would set the resulting image for its icon? Does anyone know how these two approaches compare, processing time wise? In @trahsgod's approach you would have to create an image for each resize, where in the other approach you would calculate the font size iteratively.

Comment: @Boro: Good question. I recall thinking that `new Font()` would be slow, but I was [mistaken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837410). Both are sufficiently fast that I never profiled either. The availability of a `FontRenderContext` may favor your approach.